# CSS Adding column in pricing table

Tags: html, css, blogger

Hi have this following codes taken from 
[W3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_pricing_table.asp) customized it for blogger blog post.

```css
<style>
/*----------Price Box--------------*/

.pricecolumns {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.price {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.price:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

.price .priceheader {
    background-color: #2CB8DA;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.price li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
    background-color: #FFFFEF;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.pricebutton {
    background-color: #FBA614;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="pricecolumns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="priceheader">Rent</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 18.99 / Month</li>
    <li>Test The Product on Live Market</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Rent</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="pricecolumns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="priceheader" style="background-color:#4CAF50">Buy</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 27.99 Life Time</li>
    <li>Buy Forever License</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Buy Now!</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

But the problem is. the blocks are showing one after another. Not like with 2 columns as it shown in the website.

I couldn't add following code (As the tutorial suggested) because of this code it making blogger drop down menu look weird.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in your css. **You used wrong css selector in css , a typo.**

> **Change this-**

```
.pricecolumns {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

> **to this-**

```
.price_columns {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

**Below are the approahes for 2 comlumns and 3 columns-**

> 2 Columns-

```css
/*----------Price Box--------------*/

.price_columns {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.price {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.price:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

.price .priceheader {
    background-color: #2CB8DA;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.price li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
    background-color: #FFFFEF;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.pricebutton {
    background-color: #FBA614;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    .pricecolumns {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="price_columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="priceheader">Rent</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 18.99 / Month</li>
    <li>Test The Product on Live Market</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Rent</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="price_columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="priceheader" style="background-color:#4CAF50">Buy</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 27.99 Life Time</li>
    <li>Buy Forever License</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Buy Now!</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

> 3 Columns-

```css
/*----------Price Box--------------*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.price_columns {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.price:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.price .priceheader {
  background-color: #2CB8DA;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.price li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
  background-color: #FFFFEF;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.pricebutton {
  background-color: #FBA614;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .pricecolumns {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="price_columns">
    <ul class="price">
      <li class="priceheader">Rent</li>
      <li class="grey">$ 18.99 / Month</li>
      <li>Test The Product on Live Market</li>
      <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Rent</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="price_columns">
    <ul class="price">
      <li class="priceheader" style="background-color:#4CAF50">Buy</li>
      <li class="grey">$ 27.99 Life Time</li>
      <li>Buy Forever License</li>
      <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Buy Now!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="price_columns">
    <ul class="price">
      <li class="priceheader" style="background-color:red">Buy</li>
      <li class="grey">$ 27.99 Life Time</li>
      <li>Buy Forever License</li>
      <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Buy Now!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

> Box-Sizing only for this particular section:

```css
/*----------Price Box--------------*/

.price_columns {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.price:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.price .priceheader {
  background-color: #2CB8DA;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.price li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
  background-color: #FFFFEF;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.pricebutton {
  background-color: #FBA614;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .pricecolumns {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="price_columns">
    <ul class="price">
      <li class="priceheader">Rent</li>
      <li class="grey">$ 18.99 / Month</li>
      <li>Test The Product on Live Market</li>
      <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Rent</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="price_columns">
    <ul class="price">
      <li class="priceheader" style="background-color:#4CAF50">Buy</li>
      <li class="grey">$ 27.99 Life Time</li>
      <li>Buy Forever License</li>
      <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Buy Now!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="price_columns">
    <ul class="price">
      <li class="priceheader" style="background-color:red">Buy</li>
      <li class="grey">$ 27.99 Life Time</li>
      <li>Buy Forever License</li>
      <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="pricebutton">Buy Now!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for rectifying edited the mistake.Your code worked.

Comment: Thank you but there is problem :( For 3 columns box sizing code making the blogger drop down list looks smaller & weird.

Comment: so you dont want to add box-sizing property in your blogger?

Comment: no as other codes are different, box sizing changing all. is there any other way to run this box resizing code only for this particular code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142894/discussion-between-sahil-dhir-and-mimi).

Answer (score 2):

`<div class="price_columns">` is your mistake because in the CSS you dont have class with underscore you have `pricecolumns`